# Magento "Coupon with the same code already exists"

Tags: magento, coupon

I am creating a sale for Friday for my magento store, and I want to use the same coupon codes I used for the products I had on sale last year.

So for product x, last year, I used a code similar to BFX

This year I am also having the same sale on product x, and I want to use the same coupon code, BFX.

However, when I went to create the discount and coupon, magento wouldn't let me use the same code "BFX", because it says:

"Coupon with the same code already exists"

I deleted last year's coupon last year, there are no other coupons in the store.

Is there a way to flush the old coupons so the system doesn't get confused? A way to delete those old codes that are somewhere in my site, even though I can't see them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

in my case it works properly.
First i deleted the Shopping Cart Price Rules
And then created new rule with same coupon code.
you can also check entry in table salesrule_coupon. or 
edit that Shopping Cart Price Rules and change dates, status etc.
also you should clear cache and/or session of your magento.